# Awk to put date in blank column in format MMYYYY

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to put date in column if column 1 is empty. So tried below code but doesn't work. Here input file is pipe separated, so need output also pipe separated

code 1

```
if ($1=="") {$1="date +%m%Y"}
```

code 2

```
if ($1=="") {$1=`date +%m%Y`}
```

code 3

```
if ($1=="") {$1=("Time = %m%Y", systime());}
```

required output

```
|042018|
```

sample input

```
ourceIifier|SourleName|GntCode|Dision|Suvision|ProfitCe1|Profie2|Plade|Retuiod|SuppliN
SAP|SAP_OSR_INV||||||||08AAACT2T|
```

Expected ouput

```
ourceIifier|SourleName|GntCode|Dision|Suvision|ProfitCe1|Profie2|Plade|Retuiod|SuppliN
SAP|SAP_OSR_INV|||||||042018|08AAACT2T|
```

my code :

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" 'NR>1{
if (match($14,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]{4}$/)) {
split ($14, mdy, ".");
$14 = sprintf ("%02d-%02.f-%02.f", substr(mdy[3],0,4), mdy[1], mdy[2]);
if ($1=="") {$1="SAP"}
if ($2=="") {$2="SAP_OSR_INV"}
if ($9=="") {$9="date +%m%Y"}
if ($26 ~ /^[0-9]$/) {$26=sprintf("%02.f",$26)}
if ($58~/^1000$/) {$10="27AAACT2438A1ZT";}}1' input.csv > output.csv
```

Here in column9($9) statement "if ($9=="") {$9="date +%m%Y"}" i want to put date.

Comment: What is input data for your `awk`?

Comment: Show us a proper input file and an output as expected

Comment: The questions above don't make sense for awk

Comment: Hi Inian...have edited my query..please check input file and expected output

Comment: @Anton Malyshev...have edited my query..please check input file and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your awk is gawk (GNU), to avoid an external command in a subshell:

```
$1=strftime("%m%d%y")
```

as well systime as strftime require gawk
(only really tested with mawk & original-awk)

Comment: specify that this is GNU awk feature

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to output the results and didn't get date correctly, this one works:

```
awk -v date="$(date +"%m%Y")" '$1=="" {$1=date} {print $0}'
```

Comment: Can use `1;` idiom instead of `{print $0}`.